# pyinstaller not importing chrome webdriver? selenium

Tags: python, selenium, pyinstaller

I'm using pyinstaller to create a .exe for my script to be used on another computer, the issue is when it gets compiled it imports webdriver/firefox it doesn't import the chrome webdriver which the script uses so the .exe won't run.
I'm just wondering why this is happening and how I can fix this. I am using python 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Download Chrome Driver for your machine from here: http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.20

Run it.
And then you can use your Chrome Driver by this way (port may be different):

```
from selenium import webdriver    
driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:9515', desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
```

It works fine for me.

Comment: Maybe I'm being a bit vague. The script runs perfectly on my computer, it's once I compile it to an .exe using pyinstaller it doesn't work. What is happening is pyinstaller is importing firefox's webdriver instead of the chrome webdriver. I assume I'd either have to edit the hook or there is another file I can edit to tell pyinstaller which webdriver to import. Also I don't really understand what you are trying to tell me, as from what I get from your comment is that you think my chrome driver isn't working but it is but only in script form. pyinstaller will not import the chrome web driver

Answer (score -1):

I get the same issue fixed by explicitly import the `selenium.webdriver.Chrome` in my script :

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
```

I guess pyinstaller will not then forget this Chrome sub-module.